# Why container node can not have multiple columns in wxDataViewCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

`wxDataViewCustomRenderer::Render()` is not getting called for all the columns except for first expander column.

[image]

I need to have data in multiple columns for the expander/collapser row.

How can I acheive it without modifying the wxDataViewCtrl source.

Comment: Is this question that stupid (downvote), :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you are complaining about the default behaviour of [wxDataViewModel::HasContainerColumns()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.2/classwx_data_view_model.html#ac4a3bef32f653e3f39cfde9caaec3c3d) which returns false in the base class. If you want to be able to define fields for the other columns of the expander items, you need to override this method to return true in your custom model class.